# Gitlab-CI does not generate apk after execution

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a problem to generate an APK in an android project through GitLab CI every time I run the gradle with the arguments `assemble`, `assembleRelease` or `assembleDebug` I get this error Task 'assemble' not found in root project 'MyProject'.

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file.

```
image: openjdk:8-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "27"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "27.0.3"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "25.2.5"

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1
  - wget --quiet --output-document=android-sdk.zip https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r${ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS}-linux.zip
  - unzip -q android-sdk.zip -d android-sdk-linux

  - mkdir android-sdk-linux/licenses
  - printf "8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55\nd56f5187479451eabf01fb78af6dfcb131a6481e" > android-sdk-linux/licenses/android-sdk-license
  - printf "84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > android-sdk-linux/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license
  - printf "d975f751698a77b662f1254ddbeed3901e976f5a" > android-sdk-linux/licenses/intel-android-extra-license

  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter android-${ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK}
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter platform-tools
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-${ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS}
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-m2repository
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-google_play_services
  - echo y | android-sdk-linux/tools/android --silent update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-google-m2repository
  - android-sdk-linux/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update > update.log
  - export ANDROID_HOME=$PWD/android-sdk-linux
  - export PATH=$PATH:$PWD/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleRelease --debug
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - app/build/outputs/
  only:
    - develop
  tags:
    - docker
```

When using the command `- ./gradlew build --debug` instead of `- ./gradlew assembleRelease --debug` all works but APK is not generated. Could someone help me?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the text, not an image

Comment: Okay, I edited the question as requested.

Comment: is it working outside of the pipeline? Just echo all gradle tasks by adding `./gradlew tasks` if it is there then problem lies in your project.

Comment: Hello @Ruwanka, when using the terminal within Android Studio and running the command `gradlew assembleRelease` works perfect, but when running through GitLab CI I have the problem reported.